# Writing and reading file in binary

Tags: c

The whole goal is to create generate 1000 cars with the following attributes, write them to a binary file, read them from that binary file and count them. Note that if the car is hybrid, then it will have two efficiencies, one is a float and the other is an int. The code is below because I have spent way too much time on it (two days now).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <process.h>


typedef enum {
    hybrid, ICE, electric
} engine_Type;

typedef enum {
    tesla, bmw, toyota, mercedes_benz, hyundai, volkswagen, nissan
} car_Make;

typedef union {
    int electricEffInt;
    float iceEffFloat;
} effincy;

typedef struct {
    engine_Type engine;
    car_Make make;
    int hybridEffInt;
    float hybridEffFloat;
    effincy carEfficiency;
    int maximumTorque;
} car;

//Mix is used for seed generation
unsigned long mix(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c) {
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 13);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 8);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 13);
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 12);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 16);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 5);
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 3);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 10);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 15);
    return c;
}

car carGeneration() {
    car car;
    car.engine = rand()%3;
    car.make = rand()%7;
    car.maximumTorque = (250 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(3800-250)));

    switch (car.engine) {
        case hybrid: car.hybridEffInt = (12 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (18 - 12)));
        car.hybridEffFloat = (float)(3.3f + (float)rand() / (RAND_MAX / (8.5f - 3.3f)));
            break;
        case ICE: car.carEfficiency.iceEffFloat= (3.3f + (float)rand() / (RAND_MAX / (8.5f - 3.3f)));
            break;
        case electric: car.carEfficiency.electricEffInt = (12 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (18 - 12)));
            break;
    }

    return car;
}

void mulipleCarGeneartion(int carCount, car *cars){
    for(int i =0;i < carCount ;i++){
        cars[i]=carGeneration();
    }
}

void write_file(car *cars, int amount){
    FILE*out = fopen("cars.dat", "wb");

    if(out == NULL){
        printf("File does not exist creating file");
    }

    for (int i=0;i< amount ;i++) {
        //fwrite(&cars[i], sizeof(car) , 1,out);
        fwrite(&cars[i].engine, sizeof(car) , 1,out);
        fwrite(&cars[i].make, sizeof(car) , 1,out);
        fwrite(&cars[i].maximumTorque, sizeof(int) , 1,out);

        switch (cars[i].engine) {
            case hybrid: fwrite(&cars[i].hybridEffInt, sizeof(int) , 1,out);
                fwrite(&cars[i].hybridEffFloat, sizeof(float) , 1,out);
                break;
            case ICE:
                fwrite(&cars[i].carEfficiency.iceEffFloat, sizeof(float) , 1,out);
                break;
            case electric:fwrite(&cars[i].carEfficiency.electricEffInt, sizeof(int) , 1,out);
                break;
        }

    }
    fclose(out);
}

void read_file(car *cars, int amount) {
    int teslaCount = 0, bmwCount=0, toyotaCount=0, mercedes_BenzCount=0, hyundaiCount=0, volkswagenCount=0, nissanCount=0;
    FILE *in = fopen("cars.dat", "rb");

    if (in == NULL) {
        printf("Can not read file");
    }

    printf("Car makes (Quantity): \n");
    printf("Tesla BMW Toyota Mercedes-Benz Volkswagen Nissan\n");

    for (int j = 0; j<50; j++) {
        printf("-");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        fread(&cars[i],sizeof(car), 1, in);
        printf("engine Type: %d \n", cars[i].engine);
        printf("car Make: %d \n", cars[i].make);
        printf("Torque %d \n", cars[i].maximumTorque);
        switch (cars[i].make) {
            case tesla: teslaCount++;
            break;
            case bmw: bmwCount++;
            break;
            case toyota: toyotaCount++;
            break;
            case mercedes_benz: mercedes_BenzCount++;
            break;
            case hyundai: hyundaiCount++;
            break;
            case volkswagen: volkswagenCount++;
            break;
            case nissan: nissanCount++;
            break;
        }
        switch (cars[i].engine) {
            case hybrid:
                printf("hybrid efficiencyINT: %d\n", cars[i].hybridEffInt);
                printf("hybrid efficiencyFLOAT: %f\n", cars[i].hybridEffFloat);
                break;
            case ICE:
                printf("ICE efficiency: %f\n", cars[i].carEfficiency.iceEffFloat);
                break;
            case electric:
                printf("electric efficiency: %d\n", cars[i].carEfficiency.electricEffInt);
        }
    }
    printf("Count bob %d %d %d %d %d %d", bmwCount, hyundaiCount,volkswagenCount,nissanCount, teslaCount, toyotaCount);

}

int main() {
    int generationAmount = 20;
    car carsArray[generationAmount];
    mulipleCarGeneartion(generationAmount, carsArray);
    srand(mix(clock(), time(NULL), getpid()));
    write_file(carsArray, generationAmount);
    read_file(carsArray,generationAmount);
    return 0;
}
```

I started by firstly debugging and finding the values that stored in the array. The problem now seems to with either the write function or read function. I thought doing `fwrite(&cars[i].engine, sizeof(car) , 1,out));` wrote everything about the array including the attributes, but to be honest I was not sure thus I tried to have mulitple `fwrite` to write everything about car and read them in the same order when reading the file. I tried changing the sizeof inside the fwrite, but nothing works.

**This is the current output:**

```
engine Type: 2
car Make: 1
Torque 953
electric efficiency: 16
engine Type: 1
car Make: 1363987785
Torque 2
ICE efficiency: 0.000000
engine Type: 953
car Make: 16 
Torque 32760 
engine Type: 17 
car Make: 1525 
Torque 17 
engine Type: 1525 
car Make: 1 
Torque 6 
Count bob 2 0 0 0 0 0
```

which is incorrect, car make ranges from 0-7, while engine type 0-3, and torque's minimum value is 250. What makes this problem harder is that i cant look at the binary file and understand the data to see where the problem is. I know I can convert it to hex but like what am I going to do with hex?

Comment: On Linux you can browse binary files with hexedit. Do you have a good reason for using a binary file instead of say a text csv file? Saving structs as binary data has issues as it may not be readable by another compilation instance of your program. The padding can be different. Also, if you can have efficiency of int and float then you want a struct not a union.

Comment: The code could use some formatting

Comment: If you want to read a car, you must write a car.

Comment: Just be carefull to write exacly the number of bytes you need for a specific "field", e.g. this is incorrect: "write(&cars[i].engine, sizeof(car) , 1,out);
        fwrite(&cars[i].make, sizeof(car) , 1,out);"   The sizeof should be taken of the fields engine and make.

Comment: You're reading each car with `fread(&cars[i],sizeof(car), 1, in)` so it would make sense to write each as a whole, not as individual attributes, using `fwrite(&cars[i],sizeof(car), 1, out)`.

Comment: @jarmod, 
Thank you for taking the time to write me a comment, I have tried what you have suggested, and the first few generations are correct but anything more than 5 generation leads to all kinda of weird numbers.

Comment: "File does not exist creating file" is not why a fopen would fail.  `w` truncates the file.  It will also crash if out is null so error strategy is no good.

Comment: @SimonGoater, Thank you for taking the time to comment, Simon. I have looked at the hextedit but I find it confusing at times even though I am taking a computing subject and digital logic. The reason for saving a structs as binary is because our professor told us and it is a requirment for this task. We are also told to use union somewhere, so I thought this is the best oppunity to use it because it allows me to store one value at a time, meaning if the car was a ICE then I can store ICE efficiency as a float and if the car is electric I can store the value as an int.

Comment: If you have problems (reader or writer, client or server) fix one of them and inspect the other.  For instance, inspect your file to ensure it's good now you know it's a problem with the reader.

Comment: @stark, may I ask you to clearify further? i could be wrong but I believe I am writing a car?

Comment: @AllanWind, Thank you for comment Allan, may I ask you for a suggestion for a better null error strategy? I could be wrong but when writing to a file if the file does not exist then a new file will be automaically created, isn't that right?

Comment: If you can't write to the required file return (an error) or exit(1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253000/discussion-between-daniel-boos-and-allan-wind).

Comment: Proper cite for your `mix()` is `"Robert Jenkins' 96 bit Mix Function"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First I fixed the obvious type mix-up by using the variable rather than type names to `sizeof()`:

```
        fwrite(&cars[i].engine, sizeof(car) , 1,out);
        fwrite(&cars[i].make, sizeof(car) , 1,out);
```

To debug this issue I then wrote a `cars_print()` function, disabled the print in `read_file()` (it's mixing concerns), commented out `srand()`, and reduced `generationAmount` to `1` which look fine then `2` which yielded a difference:

```
#define generationAmount 2

void print_cars(int amount, car cars[amount]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < generationAmount; i++) {
        printf("i = %zu\n", i);
        printf(
            "engine: %d\n"
            "make: %d\n",
            cars[i].engine,
            cars[i].make
        );
        switch (cars[i].engine) {
            case hybrid:
                printf("hybridEffInt: %d\n"
                    "hybridEffFloat: %f\n",
                    cars[i].hybridEffInt,
                    cars[i].hybridEffFloat
                );
            case ICE:
                printf("carEfficiency.iceEffFloat: %f\n", cars[i].carEfficiency.iceEffFloat);
                break;
            case electric:
                printf("carEfficiency.electricEffInt: %d\n", cars[i].carEfficiency.electricEffInt);
                break;

        }
        printf("maximumTorque: %d\n", cars[i].maximumTorque);
    }
}

int main() {
    car carsArray[generationAmount];
    //srand(mix(clock(), time(NULL), getpid()));
    mulipleCarGeneartion(generationAmount, carsArray);
    print_cars(generationAmount, carsArray);
    write_file(generationAmount, carsArray);
    read_file(generationAmount, carsArray);
    print_cars(generationAmount, carsArray);
}
```

and it produces the output:

```
i = 0
engine: 1
make: 4
carEfficiency.iceEffFloat: 7.451888
maximumTorque: 3030
i = 1
engine: 2
make: 3
carEfficiency.electricEffInt: 16
maximumTorque: 1440
i = 0
engine: 1
make: 4
carEfficiency.iceEffFloat: 0.000000
maximumTorque: 3
i = 1
engine: 1440
make: 16
maximumTorque: 1440
```

2. Then I looked a `write_file()` vs `read_file()` and particular paying attention to the `carEfficiency.iceEffFloat` which is problematic per above output.  I found that that you write out individual fields in particular `carEfficiency`, `hybridEffInt` and `hybridEffFloat` depending on the value of `engine`, but in `read_file()` you read a `car` struct which is not the same.  The easy fix is just to write and read the whole array in one go:

```
void write_file(int amount, car cars[amount]){
    FILE *out = fopen("cars.dat", "wb");
    if(!out) {
        printf("File does not exist creating file");
        return;
    }
    fwrite(cars, sizeof *cars, amount, out);
    fclose(out);
}

void read_file(int amount, car cars[amount]) {
    FILE *in = fopen("cars.dat", "rb");
    if (!in) {
        printf("Can not read file");
        return;
    }
    fread(cars, sizeof *cars, amount, in);
    fclose(in);

}
```

You should check the return value from both `fread()` and `fwrite()`.  It would also be a good idea to use a different array for writing the data than to read the data so nothing gets carried simply by happenstance.  This will write out an unused variable for `electric` and `ice` but it might be worth it for the cleaner code.  If you don't want that then you have to read and write fields individually.

3. The order you write is also not he same as the order of your members of struct.  `maximumTorque` is written after `make` but in the struct it's after `carEfficiency`.
4. There is data modeling issue.  `efficiency` is a union, but you have `hybridEffFloat` and `hybridEffInt` in `cars`.  The easiest fix it just use same variable name across the 3 engine types, and this means you can eliminate the (union) `efficiency` and just have that two fields in `cars` as you don't use it elsewhere:

```
typedef struct {
    engine_Type engine;
    car_Make make;
    int efficiency_electric;
    float efficiency_ice;
    int maximumTorque;
} car;
```

5. Don't encode types in variable names.  If you need to change the type this means you also have change your variable names to avoid confusion (DRY).
6. Finally, re-implement the tabulation logic you had in `read_file()`.  I noticed with my 2 records the count 1 is.  This is because you don't print out all the variables (`mercedes_BenzCount`).  Use an array instead:

```
void tabulate_cars(int amount, car cars[amount]) {
    printf("Car makes (Quantity): \n");
    printf("Tesla BMW Toyota Mercedes-Benz Volkswagen Nissan\n");

    int counts[make_count] = { 0 };
    for (int j = 0; j<50; j++)
        printf("-");
    printf("\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        counts[cars[i].make]++;
    printf("Count bob ");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < make_count; i++)
        printf("%d%s", counts[i], i + 1 < make_count ? " " : "\n");
}
```

Notice the output is slightly different and you have two functions now to print details and to tablute.  In tabulate you still hard-code the labels to match the enum order.  The way to fix that is a X macro, btw, but the answer is getting pretty long already.

7. Minor issue but prefer the array length argument before array so you can document how they are related.
8. Eliminate `carGeneration` in favor of just `mulipleCarGeneartion()` for consistency with the rest of your functions.  The former is a special-case of the latter so you don't need it.  Also rename it to `generate_cars()` for consistency.
9. `srand()` should happen before `rand()` to have an effect (i.e. before `generate_cars()`).

Here's it's altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define generationAmount 20

typedef enum {
    hybrid, ICE, electric
} engine_Type;

typedef enum {
    tesla, bmw, toyota, mercedes_benz, hyundai, volkswagen, nissan, make_count
} car_Make;

typedef struct {
    engine_Type engine;
    car_Make make;
    int efficiency_electric;
    float efficiency_ice;
    int maximumTorque;
} car;

//Mix is used for seed generation
unsigned long mix(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c) {
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 13);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 8);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 13);
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 12);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 16);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 5);
    a=a-b;  a=a-c;  a=a^(c >> 3);
    b=b-c;  b=b-a;  b=b^(a << 10);
    c=c-a;  c=c-b;  c=c^(b >> 15);
    return c;
}

void print_cars(int amount, car cars[amount]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < generationAmount; i++) {
        printf("i = %zu\n", i);
        printf(
            "engine: %d\n"
            "make: %d\n",
            cars[i].engine,
            cars[i].make
        );
        switch (cars[i].engine) {
            case hybrid:
                printf("efficientcy_eletric: %d\n", cars[i].efficiency_electric);
                printf("efficientcy_ice: %f\n", cars[i].efficiency_ice);
            case electric:
                printf("efficientcy_eletric: %d\n", cars[i].efficiency_electric);
                break;
            case ICE:
                printf("efficientcy_ice: %f\n", cars[i].efficiency_ice);
                break;

        }
        printf("maximumTorque: %d\n\n", cars[i].maximumTorque);
    }
}

void generate_cars(int carCount, car cars[carCount]){
    for(int i =0;i < carCount ;i++) {
        cars[i].engine = rand()%3;
        cars[i].make = rand()%7;
        cars[i].maximumTorque = (250 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(3800-250)));
        switch (cars[i].engine) {
            case hybrid:
                cars[i].efficiency_electric = (12 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (18 - 12)));
                cars[i].efficiency_ice = (3.3f + rand() / ((float) RAND_MAX / (8.5f - 3.3f)));
                break;
            case ICE:
                cars[i].efficiency_ice = (3.3f + rand() / ((float) RAND_MAX / (8.5f - 3.3f)));
                break;
            case electric:
                cars[i].efficiency_electric = (12 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (18 - 12)));
                break;
        }
    }
}

void write_file(int amount, car cars[amount]){
    FILE *out = fopen("cars.dat", "wb");
    if(!out) {
        printf("File does not exist creating file");
        return;
    }
    fwrite(cars, sizeof *cars, amount, out);
    fclose(out);
}

void read_file(int amount, car cars[amount]) {
    FILE *in = fopen("cars.dat", "rb");
    if (!in) {
        printf("Can not read file");
        return;
    }
    fread(cars, sizeof *cars, amount, in);
    fclose(in);

}

void tabulate_cars(int amount, car cars[amount]) {
    printf("Car makes (Quantity): \n");
    printf("Tesla BMW Toyota Mercedes-Benz Volkswagen Nissan\n");

    int counts[make_count] = { 0 };
    for (int j = 0; j<50; j++)
        printf("-");
    printf("\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        counts[cars[i].make]++;
    printf("Count bob ");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < make_count; i++)
        printf("%d%s", counts[i], i + 1 < make_count ? " " : "\n");
}

int main() {
    car cars[generationAmount];
    srand(mix(clock(), time(NULL), getpid()));
    generate_cars(generationAmount, cars);
    //print_cars(generationAmount, carsArray);
    write_file(generationAmount, cars);
    read_file(generationAmount, cars);
    print_cars(generationAmount, cars);
    tabulate_cars(generationAmount, cars);
}
```

and the resulting output:

```
i = 0
engine: 2
make: 6
efficientcy_eletric: 16
maximumTorque: 2850

i = 1
engine: 0
make: 2
efficientcy_eletric: 16
efficientcy_ice: 4.687404
efficientcy_eletric: 16
maximumTorque: 2232

i = 2
engine: 2
make: 3
efficientcy_eletric: 15
maximumTorque: 1824

i = 3
engine: 1
make: 1
efficientcy_ice: 3.948720
maximumTorque: 2400

i = 4
engine: 0
make: 3
efficientcy_eletric: 12
efficientcy_ice: 6.890365
efficientcy_eletric: 12
maximumTorque: 2543

i = 5
engine: 0
make: 0
efficientcy_eletric: 15
efficientcy_ice: 6.773261
efficientcy_eletric: 15
maximumTorque: 2722

i = 6
engine: 2
make: 2
efficientcy_eletric: 17
maximumTorque: 282

i = 7
engine: 2
make: 3
efficientcy_eletric: 14
maximumTorque: 2845

i = 8
engine: 0
make: 4
efficientcy_eletric: 13
efficientcy_ice: 4.352170
efficientcy_eletric: 13
maximumTorque: 261

i = 9
engine: 0
make: 0
efficientcy_eletric: 14
efficientcy_ice: 6.686623
efficientcy_eletric: 14
maximumTorque: 2542

i = 10
engine: 1
make: 3
efficientcy_ice: 7.677234
maximumTorque: 3004

i = 11
engine: 2
make: 2
efficientcy_eletric: 12
maximumTorque: 3486

i = 12
engine: 1
make: 1
efficientcy_ice: 6.545116
maximumTorque: 3264

i = 13
engine: 0
make: 2
efficientcy_eletric: 16
efficientcy_ice: 4.487165
efficientcy_eletric: 16
maximumTorque: 3457

i = 14
engine: 1
make: 4
efficientcy_ice: 3.627770
maximumTorque: 3655

i = 15
engine: 2
make: 2
efficientcy_eletric: 16
maximumTorque: 485

i = 16
engine: 0
make: 1
efficientcy_eletric: 16
efficientcy_ice: 4.707179
efficientcy_eletric: 16
maximumTorque: 1418

i = 17
engine: 0
make: 2
efficientcy_eletric: 16
efficientcy_ice: 4.103405
efficientcy_eletric: 16
maximumTorque: 1081

i = 18
engine: 2
make: 3
efficientcy_eletric: 17
maximumTorque: 485

i = 19
engine: 1
make: 5
efficientcy_ice: 7.746961
maximumTorque: 2728

Car makes (Quantity):
Tesla BMW Toyota Mercedes-Benz Volkswagen Nissan
--------------------------------------------------
Count bob 2 3 6 5 2 1 1
```